# How to extract SearchableText from file content?

Tags: plone

on my Plone 4.2 installation all files have the SearchableText field set to []. I don't no why, as I looked last (in december) all was right. The Live-Search don't find any file, all other content is found. Our main content are files. How can I tell Plone to build this field new? I have updated the catalog, but this took the empty field an adds it to the index catalog.

Answer (score 4):

Check that the programs that should index your files (wvware, poppler and friends) are working, and are accessible for your plone user. Running a test instance in foreground mode, you should be able to add a new document and see them active. If necessary, open another terminal, and run 'top' or 'htop' there to see if they kick in when you upload a PDF or doc. (this is a slightly linux-centric answer)

Comment: The indexer are all ok. New documents get indexed (.doc, .docx, usw.), but I have to reindex the old documents. How can I do that? Update catalog reads the index, but don't build it. How can I tell Plone to take every File and build the SearchableText field new?

Comment: Then you'll probably have to do a 'clear and rebuild'. You'll need to go to the ZMI, go to portal_catalog, and then the 'advanced' tab. There's a 'clear and rebuild' button. Remember, this can take quite some time, and can put a bit of strain on your server if there are long files/documents to index.

Comment: No need to clear and rebuild, just recatalog operation is enough.

Comment: not always, if content was added in 'strange' ways (through the ZMI, transmogrify pipeline with index step forgotten (ahum), imported through other means, ...) I've experienced several times that a 'clear and rebuild' was needed.